# How to filter all Google Analytics results by a single country?

Tags: google-analytics

I've made a filter with the settings:

- Customer
- Include
- Filter Field: Country
- Filter Pattern: Australia
- Applied filters to all views

I get the message "You are using a filtered view, which may cause your Users count to be inaccurate." but the results remain the same. I still get data from other countries.

Would anyone know how this works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filters are not retroactive, in any case I suggest you to avoid using Filters for this purpose. I personally use filters only to block spammers.

You can instead create a Custom Segment and use it when you want to see the behavior of users that visit the site from a specific country.

[image]